Jupyter Notebook doesn't detect GPU while importing tensorflow
In jupyter notebook I am importing tensorflow for my project .
It is better if the training does work on gpu so I tried running !pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow command but I got the error as follows:
subprocess-exited-with-error

python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
exit code: 1

[44 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in init
parsed = _parse_requirement(requirement_string)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement
return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement
url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_details
marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_marker
tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging_tokenizer.py", line 165, in raise_syntax_error
raise ParserSyntaxError(
setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
python_version>"3.7"
^

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
File "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1zpm1ck6\tensorflow-gpu_76e71b3a0add4c93b61fcedc949da126\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
setuptools.setup()
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init_.py", line 102, in setup
install_setup_requires(attrs)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_init.py", line 73, in _install_setup_requires
dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 655, in parse_config_files
self._finalize_requires()
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 390, in _finalize_requires
self._normalize_requires()
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 405, in _normalize_requires
self.install_requires = list(map(str, _reqs.parse(install_requires)))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in init
raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
python_version>"3.7"
^
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Encountered error while generating package metadata.

See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Please suggest a fix. I tried using my GPU for my project in Jupyter notebook. I expected tf.test.is_gpu_available() to give true as output but got as false.

"so i tried running !pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow" A) Since I also see "C:\Users\ASUS\anaconda3\...., you should always be using Anaconda/conda when possible because you choose that as your primary package manager by installing the Anaconda Distribution. Only resort to pip in cases when no conda-recipe. You'll have more robust and portable environments that way. And a lot less headaches. B) In modern Jupyter when trying to do installations from within a running Jupyter notebook file, you should be using the magic install command variations and avoid running installs ...

 in conjunction with the exclamation point. The magic install commands insure the installations occur in the correct environment, which the exclamation point option doesn't do. See more about the modern %pip install command here. The second paragraph here goes into more details about why the exclamation point may lead to issues. In your example ....

 from above the command would be %conda install conda-forge::tensorflow, based on here and the use of the magic install commands. ..... However, you should first follow what Ro.oT is suggesting and just consider points (A) & (B) in my comments as guides for future better experience while using Jupyter and Anaconda on  your machine.

What is your Python version? If it's 3.7 or lower, then you need upgrade it to a newer version between 3.9 and 3.11. I recommend creating a new virtual environment with Anaconda: conda create -n <env_name> python=3.9
Also, your OS seems to be Windows and Tensorflow versions above 2.10 does not provide GPU support on Windows. Please use the following commands from a terminal after you upgrade your python version:
conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0
# Anything above 2.10 is not supported on the GPU on Windows Native
python -m pip install "tensorflow<2.11"
# Verify the installation:
python -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"

If the above step runs successfully you should see:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

in your terminal.
Make sure, you have updated gpu driver and CUDA installed for your GPU. More details can be found here.
